# How to share sessionStorage between multiple browser tabs JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, jsp, local-storage, session-storage

I am new to storing data on client-side. I have implemented onkeyup search function. From there I am trying to get city name from AJAX and set that city name should be displayed at the top inside header of the page. So to store city name, I have used sessionStorage. I implemented it successfully but the thing is as it does not retain the session when opening that link in the new tab. **So I just want to know that is there any way to share the session between multiple tabs and displayed same value in all the tabs when opened.**

Below is my script to set and get sessionStorage for city:

```
function addcity() {
            var citydata = [], searchcity = "";
            var cityid = document.getElementById('hcity').value;
            var cityname = document.getElementById('forsearchcity').value;
            if(cityid != null && cityname != null) {
                searchcity = {cityid : cityid, cityname : cityname};
                citydata.push(searchcity);
            }
            var city = sessionStorage.setItem("city", JSON.stringify(citydata));
        } 
function getcity() {
        var city = sessionStorage.getItem("city");
        var citydata = JSON.parse(city);
        var id = "", name = "", div = "";
        if(citydata != null && citydata.length != 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < citydata.length; i++) {
                id = citydata[i].cityid;
                name = citydata[i].cityname;
                if(name != null) {
                    div = div + "<div id='user-selected-city-input'>"
                                    +"<a href='<%=WebUrl.searchcity%>'>"
                                    +"<h6>Delivery In</h6>"
                                    +"<h5 style=\"color: #330000;\">"+name+"</h5>"
                                    +"</a>"
                                +"</div>";
                }
            }
        }else{
                div = div + "<div id='user-selected-city-input'>"
                                +"<a href='<%=WebUrl.searchcity%>'>"
                                +"<h6>Delivery In</h6>"
                                +"<h6 style=\"color: black;\">Choose City</h6>"
                                +"</a>"
                            +"</div>";
        }
        document.getElementById("city_pop").innerHTML = div;
    }
```

**Any suggestions would be helpful.**

[image: Screenshot to display session storage value]

Comment: *it does not retain the session when opening that link in the new tab*. Whenever a document is loaded in a particular tab in the browser, a unique page session gets created and assigned to that particular tab. That page session is valid only for that particular tab. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: Yes, but I want that thing for all tabs when same will be open by someone. So that he/she  would be able to see his/her selected city.

Comment: Then you could either use `localStorage` in combination with `sessionStorage` and the `StorageEvent` to sync changes between storages. Or use [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) to send data between tabs. But you'll have to create a fallback for Safari with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting things in `localstorage` and have event listener for a storage event. Then if needed you can copy the content to the `sessionstorage` of the other tab.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storageevent-interface